# How to capture calendar event in QT

Tags: qt

I am new to QT GUI programming, i am stuck with a scenario where I have to display the list (files) of a directory which has been saved on a particular date.
So, whenever a user click on a particular date on the calendar widget, I need to display the content of the directory.

How can I get the event when a user click on the calendar, and how can display the content of the directory?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Connect the QCalendarWidget's clicked() signal to a function/method. It provides a QDate depresentation of the day the user selected.

Here is a full [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calendarwidget-example.html)